# Determining MLE from $x$ and $p$.

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

Currently attempting to better understand Maximum Likelihood Estimators with a sample problem that is a bit outside of my level of understanding.  Given the observation $x$, the purpose is to find the MLE of $p$.

Starting with the probability function as it given:

$f(x) = (p) \cdot (1 - p)^{x-1}$

Deriving this, yields:

$f(d/dx) = \ln(1-p) \cdot (1-p)^{x-1} \cdot (p)$

Thinking about MLEs, the goal now would be to solve for when this derivative equates to $0$.  Do I solve for $p$ or do I set $p$ to $0$?  I'm not quite sure what the correct approach here is.  The experiment represented by the probability function f(x) is run until it succeeds, at which point it stops.

The suggested response would be in the form of as an equation, which is something I have not yet encountered.

Any assistance would be quite appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Kenta S for the formatting suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to differentiate $f$ with respect to $p$, because you want to maximize the distribution $f$ with respect to the choice of parameter $p$.

The derivative would be
$$f'(p)=(1-p)^{x-1}-p(1-p)^{x-2}(x-1)$$
So if you set that to zero and solve for $p$, you get $p=\frac{1}{x}$, or $p=1$. You should be able to show that $p=\frac{1}{x}$ gives the maximum.

Comment: Sorry, I made an edit stating that the problem in question asks for the final solution in the form of an equation such as x - 1 or x^2/x.  Hence the perplexity.

Comment: Are you sure that there is only one observation? Usually with MLEs, you have multiple observations. If you had multiple observations the answer would indeed depends on each of the $x_i$ values.

I'm still a bit perplexed as to why $f$ is seemingly non-positive. Could you give any more details about the problem, like the name of the probability distribution, or the context of where the distribution is used?

Comment: Sorry, rewrote the equations.  Should be positives only.  The problem states that X is all of the trials up and to the first actual success.  So, each time the experiment is performed, p is the probability of success, yet the experiment ceases at that first success.  Does that clarify things up a bit more?

Comment: @ask39 Please see the edit I've made, I think the answer makes sense now.

Comment: Thank you.  My last question being, why is that when I'm given the equation as f(x), that I need to differentiate f'(p)?  I understand that p is the variable to maximize.

Comment: The probability distribution $f_p(x)=p(1-p)^{x-1}$ is a function of $x$, and then you define a probability function $P(p):=f_p(x^*)$ for your observation $x^*$. You end up maximizing the probability function. Of course, it's somewhat easier to think of the probability distribution as being a multivariate function $f(x;p)$, in which case we are taking the partial derivative wrt $p$. But yes, strictly speaking we are best to define a new function.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.